# Questions about VISSIM COM interface GetQueued method

Tags: python, com-interface, ptv-vissim

I'm using Python to communicate with the VISSIM traffic simulation software using its COM interface.
I'm trying to access the GetQueued information of one of my link while running a simulation.

```
import win32com.client as com
vissim_com = com.Dispatch("Vissim.Vissim")
Sim = vissim_com.Simulation
vissim_com.LoadNet(r'D:\Tracer\labprogramme\vissim\test.inp)
vnet = vissim_com.net
links = vnet.Links
link1 = links.GetLinkByNUmber(1)
Sim.Period = 3600
for i in range(3600):
    Sim.RunSingleStep()
    cars = link1.GetVehicles()
    queued_cars = cars.GetQueued()
```

The last line returns an error

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, 'Not implemented method called.', 'VISSIMCOM.HLP', 131200, -2147467259), None)
```

I have no idea for this question, is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Most of the Vissim community exchanges happen on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/groups/2524087). So you might get faster answers there. Or you could also contact PTV's technical support.